# How can I check which python script is being run given its PID?

Tags: python3, process

top is showing that some python script is using all computer resources

Sadly, I have more that one python scrip being running. How can I identify which file it is being run from?

I obtained PID using `top` command

Comment: `top -c` will show the full command line, though you may need to make your terminal wider. Pressing `c` when in interactive mode will toggle showing the full command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try reading the file named `cmdline` in the directory `/proc/<PID>/`. It is a null-joined list of the program and its arguments. Here is an example on my ubuntu for the process handling unattended-upgrades:

```
$ cat /proc/133319/cmdline | xargs -0 echo
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
```

Would that help you with your problem?